# Forward declaration of typedef structs in GBDK C

Tags: c, struct, typedef, gameboy, gbdk

I'm using GBDK C to create a Game for the original Game Boy, and I have run in to a little problem. Each room in my game needs to have different `portals`, but each `portal` needs to reference a room. Here is a cut-back version of the code:

```
typedef struct {
    Portal portals[10];
} Room;

typedef struct {
    Room *destinationRoom;
} Portal;
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? I tried adding a forward declaration of `struct Portal;` to the top of the file but it didn't help.

---

Using the following code:

```
typedef struct Room Room;
typedef struct Portal Portal;

struct Room {
    Portal portals[10];
};

struct Portal {
    Room *destinationRoom;
};
```

Gives me this error:

```
parse error: token -> 'Room' ; column 11
*** Error in `/opt/gbdk/bin/sdcc': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0xbfe3b651 ***
```

Comment: Note that the typedef is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reorder the definitions and write a forward declaration for the `Room` and `Portal` types:

```
typedef struct Room Room;
typedef struct Portal Portal;

struct Portal {
    Room *destinationRoom;
};

struct Room {
    Portal portals[10];
};
```

Note that I separated the `typedef Portal` from the actual `struct Portal` definition for consistency, even though it is not strictly necessary.

Also note that this style is compatible with C++, where the typedef is implicit but can be written explicitly this way, or with a simple forward declaration like `struct Room;`

If for some reason you cannot use the same identifier for the `struct` tag and the `typedef`, you should declare the structures this way:

```
typedef struct Room_s Room;
typedef struct Portal_s Portal;

struct Portal_s {
    Room *destinationRoom;
};

struct Room_s {
    Portal portals[10];
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem (see edits)

Comment: @bashaus: You did not reorder the definitions.  `struct Portal` must be defined first so its size is known when you define `struct Room`.

Comment: GBDK C required my struct and typedef to have different names too, so my `struct RoomStruct` has `typedef struct RoomStruct Room `

Comment: It's unfortunate that GBDK C has such requirements, the C language keeps separate namespaces for `struct` tags and `typedef` and variable names. GBDK C is no longer maintained, so you have to live with that.  Does the code compile now?

Comment: Yes and no - the typedefs and structs are no longer a problem (which means the question is answered). The next issue I have been having is about literal declarations of structs inside structs.

I decided to split this out so that each portal object is created first and then the room object is created. Thanks for asking :)

Comment: @bashaus: That's surprising, you should only get this kind of error if you declare a new `struct` tag inside a structure definition.  Separating the `typedef`s should not have this effect.  Make sure you use the same tag in the `typedef` and in the actual `struct` definition, as shown in my updated answer.